# Trouble comparing to_char(timestamp, 'day') = 'monday'

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a PostgreSQL database, I've got a table payment with a column payment_date of type timestamp. My goal is to count payments made on Monday. The following query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'day') FROM payment;
```

gives result such as:

```
thursday 
friday   
friday   
monday   
tuesday
```

However when I try to count Mondays like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payment
WHERE TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'day') = 'monday';
```

the result is 0 even though the previous query shows it should be greater than 0.
What's wrong about the second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres docs says that "full lower case day name (blank-padded to 9 chars)"

May this select solve the problem? If there are trailing spaces, maybe your comparison fails.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM payment 
WHERE RTRIM(TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'day')) = 'monday';
```

Comment: @AleksandraStępniak: alternatively you could use `to_char(payment_date, 'FMday')` - the FM modifier removes the blanks as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that helped me to resolve this case

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM payment
WHERE TO_CHAR (payment_date, 'Day') ilike 'monday%'
```